# How to define multiple parameters in Swagger?

Tags: java, annotations

I have an api with the following path

```
@PutMapping("/test/{test1}/{test2}")
```

I am not sure how to define multiple parameters in @Operation, I only know how to describe one and from what I searched on google I didn't find anything that could help me yet.

```
@Operation(
        parameters = @Parameter(name = "test1",
                description = "test1"
        )
)
```

What I want to do is to try to add a name and a description for test2 as well.

Comment: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters/ does this help?

Comment: 'parameters' is an array and you can specify more than one `@Parameter` (enclosed within a pair of curly braces)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is example

```
@Operation(
        parameters = {
        @Parameter(name = "test1",
                description = "test1"
        ),
        @Parameter(name = "test2",
                description = "test2"
        )}
)
```